# Could Eurostar have implemented a Wifi network on their train for £600 (GBP)?

Tags: economics, computers

I'm watching [this video](http://www.ted.com/talks/rory_sutherland_perspective_is_everything.html) by Rory Suterland in which he claims at 6:15 that Eurostar could have implemented a WiFi network for £600, but instead choose to spend £6,000,000 decreasing the journey time by 40 minutes.

Is this a substianted claim? This seems to be an awfully low amount to implement a working and usable Wi-Fi network for a tunnel spanning from London to Paris and then to Brussels that will work inside a train travelling through.

Comment: the wifi can/should be setup in the train itself, one transponder per carriage and a wire running through the entire train which is connected to the device which communicates with the base station and acts as the router for the train's LAN to the internet

Comment: This isn't a notable claim. In context, it was some mild hyperbole to demonstrate an unrelated point. My interpretation is that he didn't expect people to accept this literally as a genuine estimate, but merely as a strong contrast between problem-solving approaches.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the majority of travellers prefer doing without Wifi and getting to their destination faster...

Comment: 6 millions for 40 minutes less travel time also seems far too low to me, high-speed tracks are expensive, the numbers I've heard were always in the triple-digit millions or even billions.

Comment: I don't even understand the significance of this claim. It's like saying "the city chose to spend £6,000,000 on building a hospital, when they could have bought a puppy for £6".

Comment: Watching the video further he says, "5 billion pounds" (6:53).

Comment: @DJClayworth - I'm as skeptical of L6 puppy as L600 WiFi :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It certainly sounds as if he says

> Six million pounds to reduce the journey time between Paris and London by about 40 minutes. For 0.01% of this money you could have put Wi-Fi on the trains

But that was not the cost of the Channel Tunnel Rail Link (now called *High Speed 1*).  That cost has been estimated at almost £6 *billion*, [reported here](http://www.railway-technology.com/projects/highspeedone/) as £5 billion for the link and £800 million for the revamped station at St Pancras in London.

I have no idea what the cost of Wi-Fi on the trains would have been, but £600,000 (about US$1 million) seems more plausible than £600.

Comment: £600,000 seems like the right order of magnitude http://www.cctvrail.com/news_detail.cfm?item=16330

Answer (score 2):

Rory Sutherland is just mis-retelling his Eurostar example in that 2011 talk. In [an earlier 2010 talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/rory_sutherland_sweat_the_small_stuff/transcript?language=en), he correctly quotes the cost as £6 billion, which is what was reported in the news as @Henry pointed out.

Comment: You should add some details from the earlier talk, for example a short quote, to illustrate the content. This would greatly improve the answer.